# electroplating process

Tags: electroplating

I'am not familier with chemisty,& trying electroplating on brass, by using C4 H6 CUO4.H2O.But the result is unsatisfied,am I using right chemical or I have to choose another one.I yes,anyone may guide me the right one.

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE! Thanks for posting your question here. Would it be possible to provide more information about your apparatus, and what it is about the result that's unsatisfactory? It's hard to know what might be the problem without more details. Also, if you haven't already, please check out the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) pages for more information about the site more generally. Enjoy!